# Unable to access $post->image immediately after $post->image()->save($image)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

```
    $post = $request->user()->posts()->create($request->all());

    $imageData = json_decode($request['imageData']) ?: null;

    $image = $this->imageHandler->make($request['image'], $imageData);;
    $post->image()->save($image);

    Log::debug($post->image->thumbnail);
```

When I do this, `$post->image->thumbnail` in the `Log` command (and in the log itself) is null. I don't understand why this is happening - if I submit a Post the subsequently displayed views and using `$post->image->thumbnail` just fine, and if I go into `artisan tinker` I can do `$post->image` just fine. For but some reason, in the controller right after making the Post, it says it is not there. Additionally, when it calls an Algolia helper to save/index the Post, it does not include the `image` either.

**edit:** I tried this in tinker and had issues too:

`$post = factory(App\User::class)->create()->posts()->save(factory(App\Post::class)->make());` Returns the new User and Post

`$image = factory(App\Image::class)->create();` returns new image

`$post->image()->save($image);` This returns false

$image is now:

```
App\Image {#761
     filename: "placeholder2.png",
     updated_at: "2015-12-09 01:31:31",
     created_at: "2015-12-09 01:31:22",
     id: 91,
     post_id: 104,
     post: null,
   }
```

`$post->image` is null. `$image->post` is null. But $image has the post_id correctly.

If I close tinker and reopen it and `$image = App\Image::find(91)`, now `$image->post` returns the post correctly. I don't understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that after saving the image to the post, the relationship is still not loaded. But when it's queried again, the relationship will be loaded the next time.

So all I had to add after saving $image to $post was `$post->load('image');` and `$post->image` was then accessible.

Answer (score 2):

This line of code:

```
$imageData = json_decode($request['imageData']) ?: null;
```

Is setting $imageData to "null" regardless of result as far as i can see. If this is the full code, then your issues are most likely stemming from having $imageData be null at all times. Try instead:

```
$imageData = $request['imageData'] ? json_decode($request['imageData']) : null;
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, it had no effect. The way I have it seems to be working as well since imageData has been correctly getting saved with the image. Regardless, even if always null, it should have no effect on the issue I am having (the image still gets saved, just without some other JSON). I appreciate the help, though.